# Warning: Attempt to present XXX on XXX whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c

### New edit:

I run into the Warning:

> Attempt to present OneView on Another whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy.

Following is the sample code I created to show the problem.

I have two ViewController: OneViewController and TwoViewController, and subclassed the UIStoryboardSegue class.

The storyboard is like this:
[image]

Each view contains a button, triggering the segue moving to the other one.

My customer segue's code is like:

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceVC = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationVC = self.destinationViewController;

    [sourceVC.view addSubview:destinationVC.view];
    [destinationVC.view setFrame:sourceVC.view.frame];
    [destinationVC.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(320, 0)];
    [destinationVC.view setAlpha:1.0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                     animations:^{
                         [destinationVC.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)];
                         [destinationVC.view setAlpha:1.0];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [destinationVC.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [sourceVC presentViewController:destinationVC animated:NO completion:nil];
                     }];
}
```

i.e., I want to move the destinationView from right to center.

In the TwoViewController, I also have a UITextField.

The whole code in two viewcontroller is like:

OneViewController:

```
#import "OneViewController.h"

@interface OneViewController ()

@end

@implementation OneViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"One2TwoSegue" sender:self];
}

@end
```

TwoViewController:

```
#import "TwoViewController.h"

@interface TwoViewController ()

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification*)notification;

@end

@implementation TwoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender {
    [_inputBox resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Two2OneSegue" sender:self];
}

@end
```

In the TwoViewController, the reason I wrote like this is because I want to hide the keyboard before performing the segue.

Now, If I do this:

start the app => tap "Change to Two" => tap the textfield to show the keyboard => tap "Change to One"(then the keyboard will hiding, after that, the view will change) => tap "Change to Tow" => tap the textfield to show the keyboard => tap "Change to One"

Then, I got the warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

And, if I repeat once more, I will get 2 warnings...Once more again, I will get 3...and so on..

In addition, if I remove the textfield, just two buttons, everything is fine.

Could anyone help???

Comment: when is this function called? I assume you are subclassing `UIStoryboardSegue` ?

Comment: You are trying to press B2 when the previous animation is not finished, am I right?

Comment: @Roshan, yes, I'm subclassing UIStoryboardSegue